# Excel VBA Class variable emptying across function calls

Tags: excel, vba, class

I have a Class Module wherein at the top I declare amongst other things a collection

```
Dim orderCol As New Collection
```

And below all these usual variable declarations are public functions and subs that fill up that orders collection variable.

After that function is called it becomes out of context and, well, I presumed since its a class variable that it wouldn't become out of context.

Here's a part of the code that will eventually let me automate hours of painful paperwork drudgery...

'End of variable declarations

```
Public Function start() As String

    scrape_root_page
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    scrape_orders_list 'the orders collection variable gets filled up here
    setup_workbook_temp_sheet 'however when it reaches this line, that orders collection variable is out of context
```

Please let me know how I can keep my orderCol variable usable after its filled up in that scrape_orders_list function?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variable in the same function that calls the other functions...